# Visual Studio: Why don't conditional breakpoints accept F# operators?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, conditional-breakpoint

When placing a conditional breakpoint in my code, this fails:

```
"Sophie Dee" <> myString
```

However, this works fine:

```
"Sophie Dee" != myString
```

Is this fixed in VS2012?

Comment: it's a known issue here's the [issue report](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2544) if people want to vote for it. Thanks to [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8249004/matt-mccutchen) for sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breakpoints predicates, and watch expressions etc., are all using C# (and possible VB, for VB solutions - do not know). Someone was lazy, and we have to live with that.

Comment: So it's *not* fixed in 2012, then?

Comment: Same old, same old - we must suffer! (confirmed, VS2012 Ultimate RC)

Comment: I don't like the 'lazy' bit.  Authoring a debugger evaluation engine is a monumental engineering task that requires man-years of effort.  So F# just re-uses the C# EE.  But this means you need to use C# syntax in the debugger immediate window and breakpoint conditions.  It would be great to have an F# EE, but the cost/value ratio puts it way at the bottom of the priority list of IDE features.

Comment: I'm not saying any specific Microsoft researcher/employee did something wrong, it is just a rhetoric choice for complaining. I'm sure Microsoft's personnel made all the graphs and charts and decided not to spend time on this feature. To be honest, I grew used to finding other ways to solve my coding problems (and also - F# code tends to have less bugs), so it isn't really a bother.